# Accessing parent data in nested repeater, in the HeaderTemplate

Tags: asp.net, nested-repeater

Simple question, not sure there's a simple answer!

So here's the code: (I've simplified it a lot to make it easier to read)

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <h1>My header here for: <%# OuterContainer.DataItem.MyItemName %> </h1>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                My items code here
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How, in the HeaderTemplate - can I access the DataItem in the parent repeater?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I have found the answer actually:

Use:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <%# ((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem %>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: and if you're in code-behind in the `ItemDataBound` method:

    `((RepeaterItem)e.Item.Parent.Parent).DataItem`

Comment: Instead of `.Parent.Parent`(which can be incorrect) use `.NamingContainer`.

Comment: But I am getting this Error:[InvalidCastException] Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem'.

Comment: It should be cast to a Repeater, not a RepeaterItem: `((Repeater)e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer).DataItem`

Answer (score 43):

Solution given by Paul didn't work for me, but this did:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.Parent.Parent, "DataItem.YourProperty")%>
```

Comment: Can you tell me why `Container.Parent.Parent` instead of `Container.Parent`?

Comment: @Arbaaz this will depend on how many "parents" ie levels you have. eg parent of parent. Its quite similar in logic to the way jquery aproaches it if you know what i mean

Comment: Using the NamingContainer hierarchy is better.  The NamingContainer hierarchy can be understood from the markup, while the Parent hierarchy may contain extra controls such as the Table generated by the FormView.

Comment: Parent is ItemTemplate, Parent.Parent is Repeater

Answer (score 11):

This is an old thread, but it seems proper to add:

In my case I have 2 nested ASPxGridView controls (DevExpress) and Container.Parent.Parent didn't work.

To access parent's data item from child, this is what worked for me:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, "DataItem.DbField")%>
```

Answer (score 4):

If I want to retrieve a property of a parent repeater I typically do this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem, "ThePropertyName")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used as below.
Two Repeaters act as Parent and Child.below how I get Parent value of ID Column  inside Child repeater.

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem, "ID") %>
```