# How to get parent datasource Eval() inside a nested Repeater?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing parent data in nested repeater, in the HeaderTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411336/accessing-parent-data-in-nested-repeater-in-the-headertemplate)

I have a nested repeater being databound... let's say the top level repeater is an OrderRow and the inner repeaters are bound to LineItem rows from my DB.  ASPX is something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptOrder" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("OrderID") %>:<br/>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptLineItems" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("SomeColumn1"); %>
                <%# Eval("SomeColumn2"); %>
                <%# Eval("SomeColumn3"); %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddLine" runat="server" CommandArgument=<%# ???? %> />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now the button on the inner footer will be used to add a new line item... but the command argument needs to be the OrderID from the outer repeater, so we know which order to add to.  Obviously a regular Eval() call won't work here, because it will have the inner repeater's DataRowView as a source [actually, it won't, since it's in the footer].  How do I get this value?  Am I going to have to set this dynamically in the ItemDataBound event of the outside repeater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the call are serial you can use the code behind to save the last order id and use it later.

Here is the idea.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptOrder" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#GetOrderID(Container.DataItem)%><br />
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptLineItems" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("SomeColumn1"); %>
                <%# Eval("SomeColumn2"); %>
                <%# Eval("SomeColumn3"); %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddLine" runat="server" CommandArgument=<%=cLastOrderID%> />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate
</asp:Repeater>
```

and on call behind

```
public int cLastOrderID = -1;

protected string GetOrderID(object oItem)
{
  cLastOrderID = (int)DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "OrderID");

  return cLastOrderID.ToString();
}
```

What I do here is that I call the GetOrderID to return the OrderID and I save it in a global value, and then later in the footer I use this global value. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks.  Ended up doing something very similar to this with a global variable.  Just felt a bit hacky.

Comment: @Bryan its not hacky, just see how this control works in depth, and its a normal to save the last variable, and then use it. Nothing hacky.