# Accessing a nested repeater's datasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a repeater:

`<asp:Repeater ID="rptSessions" runat="server">`

Inside this I have another repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPeople" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPeople_ItemDataBound">
```

On the ItemDataBound on my parent repeater, I am setting the datasource for the child repeater.

```
  Dim dtPeople As New DataTable
  dtPeople.Columns.Add("FirstName")
  dtPeople.Columns.Add("LastName")
  dtPeople.Columns.Add("Company")
  If e.Item.DataItem("Lunch") = True Then dtPeople.Columns.Add("Dietary") <-- ***
  rptPeople.DataSource = dtPeople
  rptPeople.DataBind()
```

Now consider the html for my child repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPeople" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPeople_ItemDataBound">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <asp:Literal ID="litDietaryRequirements" runat="server"><th>Dietary Requirements</th></asp:Literal>
      </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  .....
```

On the ItemDataBound for my child repeater I would like to hide litDietaryRequirements depending on whether the column `Dietary` exists in it's datasource. I tried the following:

```
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header Then
  DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("litDietaryRequirements"), Literal).Visible = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView).Row.Table.Columns.Contains("Lunch")
End If
```

e.Item.DataItem seems to be Nothing

Comment: DataItem is always Nothing for `ListItemType.Header`. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411336/accessing-parent-data-in-nested-repeater-in-the-headertemplate

Comment: Thanks Tim, in the end I have used the value from the parents datasource to hide the literal. `DirectCast(DirectCast(e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem).DataItem, DataRowView).Row.Item("Lunch")`

Comment: @JackPettinger: Is this answer solved? If so, the best thing to do, IMHO, is to post your solution as an answer. This way anybody with a similar problem can benefit from your answer.

Comment: @ShaiCohen Thanks, I have done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this:

```
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header Then
   Dim LunchRequired As Boolean = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem).DataItem, DataRowView).Row.Item("Lunch")
   DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("litDietaryRequirements"), Literal).Visible = LunchRequired
End If
```