# check if a repeater is null

Tags: c#, containers

How do you check in `ascx` if a repeater block is null/shows no values? I am displaying its content with Container.DataItem if it helps. Other actions will essentially depend on this condition. Thanks

Comment: Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you actually want to achieve you could check the following:

- repeater.DataSource == null
   when there is no data source, then there won't be any items
- repeater.Items
   Filter the items for ItemType ListItemType.Item or ListItemType.AlternatingItem to see whether there are any items bound.
- You can also access the repeater itself from the ItemTemplate (navigate Container.Parent and cast then)  or from codebehind like here [Access Parent Repeaters DataItem Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420819/access-parent-repeaters-dataitem-property)