# Access parent data in a nested strongly typed repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Lets say I have a class structure that looks something like this:

```
public class A
{
    public string Poperty1 { get; set; }
    public string Poperty2 { get; set; }
    public List<B> Property3 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    public string Property5 { get; set; }
}
```

...and a couple of nested repeaters that look like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ItemType="A" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="<%# Item.Property1 %>" runat="server" />
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="<%# Item.Property3 %>" ItemType="B">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text="<%# Item.Property4 %>" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How would I access Property2 from the second repeater?

Comment: Do you mean DataSource="<%# Item.Property3 %>" instead of DataSource="<%# Item.Property2 %>"

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, from [Accessing parent data in nested repeater, in the HeaderTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411336/accessing-parent-data-in-nested-repeater-in-the-headertemplate), I found the following solution. It's not the prettiest, but it works:

```
<%# ((Container.Parent.Parent as RepeaterItem).DataItem as A).Property2 %>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that involved some magic property that contained the strongly typed parent... but I haven't been able to find one...

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generic Tuple as type for the inner repeater, and pass on the Item from the outer repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ItemType="A" runat="server" ID="Rpt">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="<%# Item.Property1 %>" runat="server" />
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" 
            DataSource="<%#  Item.Property3.Select(innerItem => new Tuple<A,B>(Item, innerItem)) %>" 
            ItemType="System.Tuple<A,B>">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text="<%# Item.Item2.Property4 %>" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Be aware that ReSharper will protest against using generics in ItemType!

Here is a different example, closer to something I was working on:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptWeekNumbers" ItemType="System.Int32">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" 
            DataSource="<%# Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(day => new Tuple<int,int>(Item, day))%>" 
            ItemType="System.Tuple<int,int>">
            <ItemTemplate>
                WeekNumber: <%# Item.Item1 %>, 
                DayNumber: <%# Item.Item2 %>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

When setting the DataSource for the inner repeater:

```
DataSource='<%# Eval("Property3") %>'
```

Note the single quote when setting the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the parent repeater's Item to a separate variable.

```
<script runat="server">
    A parentItem;
</script>
<asp:Repeater ItemType="A" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# parentItem = Item %>
        <asp:Label Text="<%# Item.Property1 %>" runat="server" />
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="<%# Item.Property3 %>" ItemType="B">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text="<%# parentItem.Property4 %>" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Be aware, that the assignment in the databinding expression, will render in the html the ToString value of the expression. You might want to overwrite the ToString method of your type `A`, or alternatively wrap the assignment in a helper function that returns `null`.